# Get object from object by specific value in jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this.

```
var obj = 
{
    0:{submissionID: "136169", date: "2018-02-17 14:40:00", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name1"}
    1:{submissionID: "6113", date: "2018-02-17 12:55:13", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Mozila", formName: "Name2"}
    2:{submissionID: "500", date: "2018-02-16 18:45:58", compId: "jhg2l9lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name3"}
    3:{submissionID: "306", date: "2018-02-16 18:43:45", compId: "j372155lj", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name4"}
    4:{submissionID: "50150", date: "2018-02-16 18:41:36", compId: "j37189lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name5"}
};
```

can I take one object by it's submissionID? Like SQL.  First I created the object like this.

```
var obj = 
{
    136169:{submissionID: "136169", date: "2018-02-17 14:40:00", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name1"}
    6113:{submissionID: "6113", date: "2018-02-17 12:55:13", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Mozila", formName: "Name2"}
    500:{submissionID: "500", date: "2018-02-16 18:45:58", compId: "jhg2l9lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name3"}
    306:{submissionID: "306", date: "2018-02-16 18:43:45", compId: "j372155lj", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name4"}
    50150:{submissionID: "50150", date: "2018-02-16 18:41:36", compId: "j37189lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name5"}
};
```

and just get obj[submissionID], but I had to fix my code now I have this

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: I Haven't any attemt! At first I created object like this .

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.values` and `find`

```
var idToFind = "500";
var output = Object.values( obj ).find( s => s.id == idToFind );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array instead of an object, as following:

```
var obj = 
[
    {submissionID: "136169", date: "2018-02-17 14:40:00", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name1"}
    {submissionID: "6113", date: "2018-02-17 12:55:13", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Mozila", formName: "Name2"}
    {submissionID: "500", date: "2018-02-16 18:45:58", compId: "jhg2l9lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name3"}
    {submissionID: "306", date: "2018-02-16 18:43:45", compId: "j372155lj", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name4"}
    {submissionID: "500", date: "2018-02-16 18:41:36", compId: "j37189lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name5"}
];
```

And then, create a filter function:

```
var specificID = "500";
val filteredArray = array.filter(function(element) {
    return (element.submissionID === specificID)
};
// filteredArray[0] is the object that you are looking for
```

More details on filter method can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank You. If I can't do it as an object I will

Answer (score 0):

For your kind of response just try this method :

```
var obj = 
{
    0:{submissionID: "136169", date: "2018-02-17 14:40:00", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name1"},
    1:{submissionID: "6113", date: "2018-02-17 12:55:13", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Mozila", formName: "Name2"},
    2:{submissionID: "500", date: "2018-02-16 18:45:58", compId: "jhg2l9lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name3"},
    3:{submissionID: "306", date: "2018-02-16 18:43:45", compId: "j372155lj", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name4"},
    4:{submissionID: "50150", date: "2018-02-16 18:41:36", compId: "j37189lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name5"}
};
```

If this is the response then use the below method for getting the desired answer :

```
for (var i = Object.keys(obj).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     if (obj[i].submissionID==="500") {
        var obj2 = obj[i];
        console.log(obj2);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `Object.keys` and `Array.reduce` to get the map out. Note: It turns out that your syntax of declaring objects is incorrect as it is missing commas.

```
var x = {
    0:{submissionID: "136169", date: "2018-02-17 14:40:00", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name1"},
    1:{submissionID: "6113", date: "2018-02-17 12:55:13", compId: "j1hrxej5", browser: "Mozila", formName: "Name2"},
    2:{submissionID: "500", date: "2018-02-16 18:45:58", compId: "jhg2l9lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name3"},
    3:{submissionID: "306", date: "2018-02-16 18:43:45", compId: "j372155lj", browser: "Chrome", formName: "Name4"},
    4:{submissionID: "50150", date: "2018-02-16 18:41:36", compId: "j37189lj", browser: "Opera", formName: "Name5"}
}


function remap(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(m, key){
        let item = obj[key];
        m[item.submissionID] = item;
        return m;
    }, {});
}

var newMap = remap(x); //"{"306":{"submissionID":"306","date":"2018-02-16 18:43:45","compId":"j372155lj","browser":"Chrome","formName":"Name4"},"500":{"submissionID":"500","date":"2018-02-16 18:45:58","compId":"jhg2l9lj","browser":"Opera","formName":"Name3"},"6113":{"submissionID":"6113","date":"2018-02-17 12:55:13","compId":"j1hrxej5","browser":"Mozila","formName":"Name2"},"50150":{"submissionID":"50150","date":"2018-02-16 18:41:36","compId":"j37189lj","browser":"Opera","formName":"Name5"},"136169":{"submissionID":"136169","date":"2018-02-17 14:40:00","compId":"j1hrxej5","browser":"Chrome","formName":"Name1"}}"

newMap["50150"]; //"{"submissionID":"50150","date":"2018-02-16 18:41:36","compId":"j37189lj","browser":"Opera","formName":"Name5"}"
```